# Complex Set Operation, Find Cardinality of Result

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let the $M = [m_{ij}]$ be a square, $n$ x $n$ matrix where $n \ge 2$ and all $n^2$ entries are distinct.

Let $S = \{ m_{ij} : 1 \le i,j \le n \}$. In other words, $S$ is the set containing all entries in the matrix $M$ so that $|S| = n^2$.

Let $T_{ij} = \{ m_{ij}, m_{ji}, m_{ii}, m_{jj} \}$ where $1 \le i < j \le n$. Note this results in $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ sets.

Let $R_{ij} = \{T_{ij} \cup p : p \in \mathcal P(S-T_{ij}) \}$. In other words, each element of $R_{ij}$ is the union between $T_{ij}$ and an element of the powerset of $S - T_{ij}$.

**What is the cardinality of the following set:**

$$ \bigcup_{i<j} R_{ij}$$

In other words, I am trying to derive a function $f : \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : x \ge 2 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(n) = |\bigcup_{i<j} R_{ij}|$.

Thus far I've determined that $f(n) \le n(n-1)2^{n^2-5}$. Any suggestions or answers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why is $|S|=n^2$? Are you assuming all entries of $M$ are distinct?

Comment: yes! Thanks for asking that question. I updated the post to include that important detail.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Please read the post carefully. "All $n^2$ entries are distinct." Hence, $M$ cannot be an identity matrix.

Comment: The ij_k indexing is a mess.  k is still unrelated to ij.  Sum on i < j.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M = [m_{ij}]$ be a $n$ x $n$ matrix.
Let $S = \{ m_{ij} : 1 \le i,j \le n \}$.
For i,j in {1,2,.. n}, let
T$_{ij}$ = { $m_{ii}, m_{ij}, m_{ji}, m_{jj}$ }
R$_{ij}$ = { T$_{ij} \cup$ K : K subset S - T$_{ij}$ }.

|$R_{ij}$| = 2$^{n^2 - 4}$.
The cardinality of $\cup_{i<j}$ R$_{ij}$.
is equal to or less than n(n - 1)2$^{n^2 - 5}$.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that n(n−1)2n2−5 is an upper bound. However, there is certainly overlap between the sets that are being unioned. I'm trying to sift through the overlap.

Comment: Yes, S is in every R.  @RyRytheFlyGuy